# Getting URL without the parameter

Tags: angular

Is there a way in Angular to extract a path without the parameter in the URL?

Let's suppose I have the following URL: `http://myapp.com/1005/Customers`

Where `1005` is the parameter, but I want only the segments after the parameter, in this case `Customers`.

Fow now I'm using `split` for that. Can I achieve that with an more elegant way?

Comment: Will there only be 1 segment after the parameter, or will there be more than just one?

Comment: That is a point. For now one, but I think with be one more.

Comment: `window.location.pathname.split( '/' )[2]` Do you actually do it like this ? This is by what I know the easiest and shortest solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ActivatedRoute`. You just need to import it in your constructor: `private route: ActivatedRoute`.

Then you can subscribe to the params:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params: Params){
   //Access your param or iterate over the keys.
   this.params['Customers']
})
```

Comment: This does not return the path without the parameter, this returns the parameter itself! I need the path after the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to build relative url from Route configuration:

```
    let path = '';
    let currentRoute = this.route.snapshot;
    while (currentRoute) {
      if (currentRoute.routeConfig) {
        path += currentRoute.routeConfig.path + '/';
      }
      if (currentRoute.children && currentRoute.children.length > 0) {
        currentRoute = currentRoute.children[0];
      } else {
        currentRoute = undefined;
      }
    }
```

This code will give you a way to obtain something like /part/subpart/:param/otherpart